# how can save some 3d images in a 4d array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, deep-learning, keras

I want to read the information about 256 X 512 RGB images( I'm recording the data on my laptop in C:\folder_test). it  So it is a 3D array with shape (256,512,3) third dimension holds the color R, G and B

Now, I want to (load) read 45 such images and make a array of these images. So I decide to make a 4D array which will have dimension (45, 256, 512, 3) here 45 in first dimension is the number of images and the second, third and fourth dimension are the dimension of the image which are (256 , 512 , 3)

I tried doing it using concatenate but I get errors. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: how are you reading the images?

Comment: Paste your code, that you have tried here in code block, to make your question/problem more understandable.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Essential information would be your code and the complete traceback of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np
import glob

images = np.array([misc.imread(fname) for fname in glob.glob('./*.png')])
print(images.shape)
```

Change the path to your local directory.

Comment: `scipy.misc.imread` is deprecated and will be removed in SciPy 1.2.0. Can use `imageio.imread` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to expand dimensions before you concatenate:

```
import numpy as np
pics = [np.random.sample((256 , 512 , 3)) for i in range(45)]
pics = [np.expand_dims(pic, axis=0) for pic in pics]
np.shape(np.concatenate(pics))
```

This will give you (45, 256, 512, 3), while each entry in pics has the shape (1, 256, 512, 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) which is **PIL** with it's old name to load image and [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) to convert image to an array in an efficient way.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open("YOUR_IMAGE_PATH")
array = np.array(image)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a **list** variable and append the images one by one as following :

```
imageCollection = []
for oneImagePath in (imagePaths):
  #code for reading the image
  image = ....     # image contains (256,512,3) shape image.
  imageCollection.append (image)
```

That's it. **imageCollection** is what you want.